# Conditional splitting in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to split a string in javascript (no jquery).
This is basically received fron csv.
so, i have a string,

```
string = '"abc, xyz, mno","lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl"';
```

Note: Number of commas in quoted parts is not fixed for example, `"abc, xyz, mno"` can also be `"abc, xyz, mno, klm, ..."` or `"lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl"` could have been just `"lmn"`; i.e no comma at all.

I want to split it as

```
str1 = 'abc, xyz, mno';
str2 = 'lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl';
```

I can't do this with `string.split(",");`, due to undefined number of commas.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use `string.split('","');` and then remove the excess `"` with `string.replace("\"", "");` ?

Comment: string.split(",") tends to split the string on all the commas. so when i string.split() on '"abc, xyz, mno","lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl"' it will return 7 parts not 2 :(

Comment: I corrected .. I meant to split on the quotes AND commas

Comment: Why not split on ," ?

Comment: Does `JSON.parse("[" + '"abc, xyz, mno","lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl"' + "]")` work?

Comment: Is this coming from a CSV file? There are Javascript CSV libraries that can parse it.

Comment: I can't do split on ," too, since in csv " is optional; so if i take case 2 of note i gave, '"abc, xyz, mno",lmn', here there is no quote to split on. it could also be just 'abc,lmn' :(

Comment: @Xufox, I'll try that

Comment: @Barmar do you know any? any links will be appreciated

Comment: @N41 See the duplicate links I just provided

Comment: @N41 If the `"` quotes are optional, then `JSON.parse` also won’t work. You’d need to use a CSV parser. (Time for a TC39 proposal on a built-in CSV parser?)

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the link, I'll check for possible solutions there, also, I'll go through below answers and update. :)

Comment: @Xufox, probably :P

Comment: Thanks @Barmar for the link. I modified the solution provided by _@niry_, works great ;)

Comment: Modified ans for ref :: function c2A(text){let p='',row=[''],ret=[row],i=0,r=0,s=!0,l;for(l of text){if('"'===l){if(s&&l===p)row[i]+=l;s=!s;}else if(','===l&&s)l=row[++i]='';else if('\n'===l&&s){if('\r'===p)row[i]=row[i].slice(0,-1);row=ret[++r]=[l=''];i=0;}else row[i]+=l;p=l;}return ret;};function t1(str1){let test=str1;var tab1=c2A(test);var str=[''];for(i=0;i<2;i++)str[i]=tab1[0][i];document.write("<b>InputString:</b><i>"+str1+"</i></br>");document.write("<b>str1=</b>"+str[0]+'</br>'+"<b>str2=</b>"+str[1]+'<hr>');}t1('"abc,xyz,mno","lmn,pqr,bcd,jkl"');t1('"abc,xyz,mno",lmn');t1('mno,lmn');

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple characters in the `String#split` method :

```
str.split('","')
```

***Demo:***

```js
let str = '"abc, xyz, mno","lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl"';

let result = str.split('","')
console.log(result);
```

---

If you want to get rid of the quotes, juste add a

```
.map(s => s.replace('"',''))
```

***Demo:***

```js
let str = '"abc, xyz, mno","lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl"';

let result = str.split('","').map(s => s.replace('"',''));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Zenoo, It does work if the string has quotes. Since quotes are optional, I cannot use this solution. However, I have found the solution on duplicate link provided. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best done with a regular expression. But, since they aren't my strongest area, here's how it could be done with a combination of [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
let input = '"abc, xyz, mno","lmn, pqr, bcd, jkl"';

// Split where "," is found
// Create a new array that is a copy of the original
// but with \" removed from the elements
let output = input.split('","').map(s => s.replace('\"',''));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Scott, It does work if the string has quotes. Since quotes are optional, I cannot use this solution. However, I have found the solution on duplicate link provided. :)